# Retrieving the number of occurences of each date in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe called df that has a column named date, that has many dates not unique. I want to create another dataframe with 2 columns : 1 called date and the other called count, for each date I want to know how many times it got repeated.

I used the method value_counts like this `date_count=df['date'].value_counts()` , this returns a Series object with the data as index? and the value as the only column (I didn't really understand this part and how the date got returned as the index).

I then used `date_count=date_count.to_frame()` but still same problem.
I chose using value_counts() because it does the job as it removes duplicates and gives me the number of repetitions.

My questions are :1- How can I achieve getting a dataframe with date on a column and it's count value on second column?

2-Why does the date become an index on `value_counts()` method?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you provide a example of your data?

Comment: Try the `groupby` method. First import pandas (i am assuming you have done this) and then  `df.groupby('date')[['date']].count()`

Comment: and if you want the groupby column to be a column (by default its an index when used in groupby) then try:                             `df.groupby('date')[['date']].count().reset_index()`

Comment: or: `df['date'].value_counts().reset_index()`

Comment: @BrunoMello is there a proper way to post the jupyter cell output?

Comment: Format it as code

Comment: @BrunoMello like example of data is just like the one given below in the answer

Comment: Generally in pandas whenever you perform any sort of aggregation (value_counts() is essentially grouping by the specified column then returning the count of values for each group) pandas returns the groups in the index and the aggregation as columns. So as @dimitris_ps has mentioned the usual pattern is to reset_index()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work with `value_counts()`:

```
In [446]: df2                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[446]: 
        dates
0  20-03-2020
1  21-03-2020
2  20-03-2020
3  22-03-2020
4  20-03-2020

In [451]: df = df2.dates.value_counts().reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'dates', 'dates': 'counts'})                                                                                                 

In [452]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[452]: 
        dates  counts
0  20-03-2020       3
1  22-03-2020       1
2  21-03-2020       1
```

Comment: Thank you , does exactly what I want.

Comment: Can you please tell me what did reset_index() do here?

Comment: `reset_index()` converts the index of the df to a column.

Comment: as I can see here you converted index columns which had dates to a column and then renamed it to dates , but why does is it still display the index of lines?

Comment: That is by default. Every row in a dataframe has to have an index. Hence, it displays that.

Comment: okay , got it. Just one more question is how to sort it by date? i used ```df.groupby(level='dates')``` but it displays this ValueError: level name dates is not the name of the index

Comment: I used ```df.groupby('dates')``` but it gives me this error 
<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x00000252E9AABC88>

Comment: I solved it by using ```df.sort_values(by='date')``` , I just was confusing between sort and groupby.

Comment: @Mohamed20 Note that `<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x00000252E9AABC88>` is NOT an error.